# logic behind Static methods-static variable

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I am having trouble understanding why in Java static methods can't access nonstatic variables. Could anyone explain the reasoning behind such a language design choice?

Comment: Non-static variables are associated with a particular instance; static methods are not.

Comment: you can learn this article here : https://www.quora.com/Java-programming-language-Why-cant-a-static-method-directly-access-non-static-members

Comment: Still I don't see the intuition behind such a design choice, Why the method can't access the non static data?
Why does the compiler shoot out an error like "non-static variable u cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for the quora link now I see